# is there a dashboard of notification in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, notifications

At the moment all my subscriptions goes to my emails which can easily create filtering issues and make it very much not interactive. In all the other forges I've used so far (GitTea, bitbucket and GitHub) it is possible to get personnal notifications gathered in a "notifications dashboard". In ADO I only found the "my work" button which turns out to be less useful as I can only monitor:

- work items assigned to me (where are the one that I created, or the one from a project I follow ? )
- PR that I created (same question, I want to see everything on certain repo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First open your organization page: https://.visualstudio.com/, there you will find 3 tabs:

- projects: the list of the projects within the org
- My pull requests: PR informations
- My Work items: work items informations

The last 2 tabs are way richer than the "my work" notification and can act as a dashboard. You will see what you "created", "follow" and "assigned to you". Items disappear when they are closed/merged.

[image]